# regex: Find all groups of consecutive groups, where the groups are separated by pattern

Tags: python, regex

I have a badly parsed text where multiple text blocks are separated by lines with only three digits. What I want is to get a regex that would help me capture all the text in a block (starting and including the three digits row until the last white space before the next three characters.

This is the one I've tried, but as it uses a lookahead the last group is not captured.
`\n*((\d{3})\n*([\S\s]+?)(?=\s\d{3}\s))`

Sample:

```
foo
000

foo bar
foo

461

long
multiline
text

999

last example
until rest of document
```

Expected groups:

```
[000

foo bar
foo
] Group 1
[461

long
multiline
text
] Group 2
[999

last example
until rest of document] Group 3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this solve your problem? You need to add "$" to match the last group. "$" means the end of the text.

```
import re

pattern = r'(\d{3}(.|\n|\r)*?)(?=\d{3}|$)'

for match in re.finditer(pattern, text):
    print(match.group())
    print('=' * 50)
```

Output:

```
000

foo bar
foo


==================================================
461

long
multiline
text


==================================================
999

last example
until rest of document
==================================================
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a negative lookahead to match all lines that do not contain the starting group token. This way the end of file is not a problem.

```
(^\d{3}$(?:(?!^\d{3}$)[\s\S])+)
```

Analising it:

- `(^\d{3}$(?:(?!^\d{3}$)[\s\S])+)` Our only group. Every match will contain one
- `^\d{3}$` The token that marks the start of a group. 3 digits alone in a line
- `(?:(?!^\d{3}$)[\s\S])+` The rest of the group. Match all consecutive characters that match the rule, but don't capture them one by one `(?:xxx)`
- `(?!^\d{3}$)[\s\S])` Match a character including linebreaks `[\s\S]` that are not succeeded by the group start token.

[Try it in regexr](https://regexr.com/78b4i)

I used the answer https://superuser.com/questions/1279062/regex-matching-line-not-containing-the-string#1279115 to "match all lines that don't contain a string"